# How to iterate through an HTML list in Jinja?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am using Jinja with flask and im trying to go over a list with a for statement but it shows nothing in the main view.

Here is the HTML code:

````html
<div class="container mt-4">
    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="card-deck">
            {% for CleverHub in CleverHubs %}
            <div class="card border-dark mb-3" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h4>{{ CleverHub }}</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```html
and the script goes like this 
```js
<script>
    var CleverHubs = {{amountOfCleverHubs}}
    console.log(CleverHubs)

</script>
````

The console shows an array: `[0]`

For each device it adds a 0 the list.

Comment: That depends on what CleverHubs contains on the back-end.